# how can i get the cursor's position in a editable view while using keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextinput

i have implement a view confroming UITextInput protocol,(my view is not a class of UITextview or UITextfield)

and how can i get the cursor's position to comunicate with the keyboard?

thanks , guys~

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check out [A Guided Tour of a UITextInput Implementation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW25) from the docs. There is sample code which shows how to do this: in `-setSelectedTextRange:` you can update the cursor position using the selected text range.

Comment: this function is to set cursor to a speicial position? i want just know the cursor position

Comment: No, I think you implement this method and it gets called automatically. However I haven't done this myself; you'll just have to try it.